# How force the UI message loop to flush in iOS before continuing

Tags: ios, iphone, multithreading, uikit

I have an application that experiences a brief delay when switching views, on the order of 500-1500ms. The change in views is subtle, so I need to provide feedback to the user that something DID just happen.

I would like to use a "Loading" overlay. Unfortunately, the work that is occupying the CPU is related to building the UI, and therefore cannot be moved to a background thread.

Since the work is occupying the main thread, if I add a loading overlay before the other operation starts, it never gets shown because the thread is working on the next workload and won't update the UI until it gets around to it.

Some operating systems have a DoEvents or FlushMessagePump method that can be used in the rare circumstances like these. Is there such a thing in iOS? SetNeedsDisplay() is not what I want, as it will only queue the update in the message pump.

Alternative suggestions are welcome too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show your loading overlay, and then use `- (void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anArgument afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay` with a delay of 0 to do your actual loading. This will delay your loading until the screen has a chance to refresh, because it will queue the selector on the main thread's run loop.

Comment: You nailed it. Thank you very much.

Comment: @TwoRedCells Glad I could be of help.

Comment: FWIW this only works (for me) with a non-zero value. e.g. 0.1

Answer (score 3):

Instead of delaying your loading, you can force the run loop to run:

```
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Comment: Didn't know that one! But I like it ;)